# Snowflake: how to throw an exception in a stored procedure if it is called inside the main procedure doesn't exist or not callable?

Tags: sql, exception, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a procedure P1 which is calling procedure P2. I need to handle the exception when P2 doesn't exist.

Currently it is throwing

> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 3 at position 4 : SQL compilation error: Unknown user-defined function P2'

Is there any way to handle this exception differently?

```
P1()
BEGIN
    call P2();
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this to handle exceptions?

```
create or replace procedure test_procedure()
    returns VARCHAR
    language sql
AS
declare
      msg VARCHAR DEFAULT '';
begin
  begin
    CALL P2();
  exception
    when other then
     msg := msg || ' P2 does not exist but it is OK...';
  end;
 begin 
    CALL P3();
  exception
    when other then
     msg := msg || ' P3 does not exist but it is OK';
  end;
 return msg;
end;

CALL test_procedure();
```

Comment: Actually I am calling multiple procedures(like P2, P3, P4) inside the main procedure(P1). I don't think that above option will work in this case.

Comment: @Yanki141 actually this one handles all exceptions, so it should work. Don't focus on the error message. If you want to continue to run the procedues, you can use multiple begin ends.. updated the sample

Comment: I need to raise a run time exception if any procedure is missing. The main procedure should not advance when any calling procedure does not exist.

Comment: @Yanki141 Your sample code already throws an exception. Do you need to raise a custom exception?